# Software buttons in the android 4.2 emulator not showing up (tablet)

Tags: android, android-emulator, back-button, android-homebutton

I just installed the latest Android ADT bundle from [the developer site.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) It's version  v21.0.0.

Now I wanted to test my tablet app (designed for 10.1" xlarge mdpi) in the emulator, but I cannot get any software buttons for home/back/...

Here's my device configuration. This config is afterwards assigned to the avd.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7xvP.png]

Hardware-buttons don't work as well (you cannot set hardware buttons in a tablet-like emulator).

The target api is level 15 (android 4.0.3).

Comment: The built-in 10.1" tablet profile has working software buttons. Why do you have "keyboard" checked in your "Input" area of the device configuration? I would compare this and other settings with the standard 10.1" tablet profile until you determine where you are going wrong.

Comment: OK, I get an exception: Tablet device cannot show navigation bar and system bar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422275/unfortunately-system-ui-has-stopped tells me to set hw.mainKeys to true. But in the new emulator, I cannot do this anymore :-(

Comment: OK, got it. I changed the property in C:\users\<name>\.android\avd\<emulator>.avd\config.ini and now it works. This sucks, but it works... Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Open AVD Manager , then check you device , click `edit` , then in the `Hardware`  you can see `Add` button , click on it , and check all what you want there. But there can be a problem , that for example you choose some device who don't have any buttons home or something , I mean these buttons are in the screen , not out of this , for example like [this](http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2011/08/galaxy-tab-7.7-product-image-lead-1314834951.jpg)