# Android emulator error: "System UI has stopped"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adt

I have recently set up my Android development environment. Every thing is alright but when I run my emulator it takes to much time with an error dialog on the emulator screen says- "Unfortunately, System UI has stopped" and no application runs on it.
I have recently shifted to 64bit windows7 and using JDK7 and eclipse juno for 64bit.
My emulator configuration is given below:
[image]

can anyone suggest me what is wrong with it?

Comment: Try deleting the current AVD profile and create a new one. Sometimes it worked for me. Try to decrease the screen size and also RAM size.

Comment: use this way. I had same problem but <https://stackoverflow.com/a/4648123/13011212>

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This is still "unanswered", but it probably has been resolved.

I just want to share my experience and clarify a few things, some of which may not matter. Anyway, if this helps someone else that's great.

1. I had this problem on one machine (a new, but slower machine), but not another (the faster one) when running a 4.0.3 emulator. It is not a hardware problem though, and CPU speed doesn't make a difference.
2. Both machines are fully up-to-date ADT (Eclipse 4.2.x and Android 4.2.2 (API 17) SDK environments.
3. Editing, or even Deleting the emulator and then recreating it did **NOT** fix it.
4. The best solution is to locate and update the config.ini file. In Windows 7 (x64) I found the config.ini file in **%USERPROFILE%\.android\avd**. It was located in a folder **ICS_4.0.3_API_15.avd** [*see AVD names below].

**NOTE:** First make sure you have **“show hidden files, folder, or drives”** turned on in Explorer or you won't see the ".android" folder.

5. Not sure it matters, but my entry said **hw.mainKeys=no**, not hw.mainKeys=false as some have suggested. Changing it to **hw.mainKeys=yes** seems to have fixed the problem.

- AVD Names - Your AVD name will be different from mine. I just add the Release name/API level in the name so I can quickly scan the list and go to a release, such as Honeycomb, Ice Cream Sandwich, Jelly Bean, etc. (e.g., ICS_4.0.3_API_15.avd)

There's more information in another thread at < [Unfortunately System UI has stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422275/unfortunately-system-ui-has-stopped) >. It starts by asking a seemingly tangential question, but gets to the same place.

Comment: Thanks it solve ui problem but yet it will display an launcher crash issue.

Comment: By default, the android tool creates the AVD directory inside ~/.android/avd/ (on Linux/Mac)

Comment: Worked for me on an 10.1 in.  android 4.0.4 emulator I downloaded today, though there are still some popups showing like, when changing the background, it says "Unfortunately, the process com.android.launcher has stopped"

Comment: For me it was the exact opposite -.-' I had to disable main keys to have soft keys back, then it worked. API 26 - emu 27.3.10-4969155

Answer (score 30):

**This issues has happened to me a few times, and has always been resolved by cold booting the emulator.**

On OS X:

- Open Android Studio. Navigate to Configure **>** AVD Manager.
- Under Actions **>** dropdown triangle on the right **>** Cold Boot Now:

[Here is a photo of what the menu looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2alB.png)

I'm not sure what this looks like on Windows, maybe someone can confirm that it is similar?

Comment: Works great, and the interface is the same on Linux. Very likely the same on Windows as well.

Comment: Android Studio 2021 -> Tools -> AVD Manager

Comment: In 2022 it's Tools -> Device Manager.

Answer (score 8):

What seems to have worked for me and others is to change the hw.mainKeys setting in your config.ini to true:

```
hw.mainKeys=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Close avd and eclipse then Delete .android file created in your user folder then try to create a new emulator this help me most of the time.It  may helps you

Answer (score 0):

My case. Android SDK was placed here `D:\android-sdk\` for a nearly year ago. After one of recently SDK updates I'v got "Unfortunately, System UI has stopped". I'v created number of divices with different RAM  amount, VM heap size, screen size, API level(problem seems to be only on API14+), etc. At finish i noticed that new devices was created at the location `C:\users\XuserX\.android\avd` 
After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841766/possible-to-change-where-android-virtual-devices-are-saved) post solution was simple: create `ANDROID_SDK` and `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` system variables with value `d:\android-sdk\`

Hope this post helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

just switch off and on hte button in emulator ... it can remove that problem

Answer (score 0):

This is also happening if your **device definition** name has `"` character in the name, like Kindle Fire HD 7".

Once I removed the apostrophe symbol, error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio `Tools -> AVD manager -> Actions -> dropdown`▾`-> Wipe Data`

Answer (score 0):

Go AVD Manager and just click ***"Wipe Data"*** for your emulator in Android Studio.

[image]