# Emulator: System UI isn't responding, horrible app glitches

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have multiple emulators provided by Android Studio. I have a Pixel 3 and a Pixel 4 both running Android api 30. Both work fine for a while, but eventually there is this popup:
[image: System UI isn't responding]

After this point, the emulator becomes unusable. Notice that the home and back buttons at the bottom of the screen are gone. The emulator glitches horribly, with animations slowing down and leaving residue on the screen.

**What I have tried**

Quitting the emulator application and turning it back on again. Same issue again.

Pressing the emulator power button and restarting the emulator like I would a physical device. Same issue.

Deleting the emulator and creating new one. This works for a while but eventually the error happens again.

I followed the advice here: [Android emulator error: "System UI has stopped"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678520/android-emulator-error-system-ui-has-stopped?noredirect=1&lq=1)
The .ini file had no entry for *hw.mainKeys* so I tried adding it. No effect.

**Stats**

MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)

processor: 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7

memory: 16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4

graphics: AMD Radeon Pro 5300M 4 GB, Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

Android studio 4.4.1

At this point, it's becoming difficult to continue development, since I have to keep recreating my emulator and reinitializing the device data that I need for testing.

Comment: Do they start to become unstable after you installed your app? Can your app be the issue? Have you try to uninstall your app when this problem appears to see if it fixes it?
Other way to consider: is your emulator up to date? (see SDK Tools under the SDK Manager)

Comment: So I think android studio updated during the night, and the problem completely went away. I haven't had it at all for several days. I'm tentatively going to say that it's fixed

Comment: @NickCardoso Why do you think it's a troll comment? I had an issue with the SystemUI not working after doing something wrong in the app (basically providing an app icon too big for SystemUI to managed). As other pointed out, it could also be the emulator not being up to date.

Answer (score 0):

The fixes reported by some users are in the following list. However each of the fixes have worked only for some small group of users.

- Update your HAXM version (check manually in SDK manager)
- Use a lower resolution emulator
- Try a different API version or system image

The only fix that works for all users is to wipe your emulator and start it again (which means setting up your accounts again). This fixes it for short times but the problem always returns pretty fast.

The problem has been common since at least late 2017, on both windows & mac. There was a starred issue on Google bug tracker too but I cannot find the related question on StackOverflow which linked to it